# CTypes Callback Function not being called

Tags: python, c, callback, ctypes

I am relatively new to CTypes and I have been writing a Python package to wrap a C library that was compiled to run on linux (I also do not have access to the source only the compiled shared object and header files.)

From the header file; I have been given the following function callback signatures,

```
typedef void (*pxgrid_notification_cb)(jw_dom_node *node, void *arg);
typedef jw_dom_node *(*pxgrid_query_cb)(jw_dom_node *request, void *arg);
typedef void (*pxgrid_connection_disconnect_cb)(pxgrid_connection *connection, PXGRID_STATUS status, void *user_data);
typedef void (*pxgrid_connection_connect_cb)(pxgrid_connection *connection, void *user_data);
typedef void (*pxgrid_connection_account_cb)(pxgrid_connection *connection, PXGRID_STATUS status, void *user_data);
typedef void (*pxgrid_connection_ssl_ctx_cb)(pxgrid_connection *connection, void *ssl_ctx, void *user_data);
typedef int (*pxgrid_log_cb)(const char * format , va_list ap);
typedef size_t(*pxgrid_password_cb)(char * passwd , size_t size,void * user_data);
```

For the custom types in the signatures I have defined the types as structures using the ctypes.Structure class.

```
class pxgrid_connection(Structure): pass
class jw_dom_node(Structure): pass
class va_list(Structure): pass
```

***As a side note I have also tried exporting the jw_dom_node type from the library itself but was given the error that is was not able to find the symbol. Which I believe is due to the fact they are more than likely not exporting that from the compiled code. This was attempted with the following code;

```
self.jw_dom_node = c_int.in_dll(lib, "jw_dom_node")
```

I have used the c_int type as I have read that this is the default type for ctypes. Back to my previous train of thought,

After defining the custom Structures I then declare the signatures,
*** 'core_instance' is actually a representation of my core module, the following signatures are defined in my callbacks module and when my core module is instantiated self is passed in as an argument into the instantiation of my callbacks module. So core_instance is just my way of referencing these types from my Core class.

```
self.pxgrid_connection_connect_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.pxgrid_connection), c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_connection_disconnect_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.pxgrid_connection), c_int, c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_connection_account_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.pxgrid_connection), c_int, c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_notification_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.jw_dom_node), c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_query_cb = CFUNCTYPE(core_instance.jw_dom_node, POINTER(core_instance.jw_dom_node), c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_connection_ssl_ctx_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.pxgrid_connection), c_void_p, c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_log_cb = CFUNCTYPE(int, POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p), core_instance.va_list)
self.pxgrid_password_cb = CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_size_t, POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_size_t, c_void_p)
self.pxgrid_message_cb = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(core_instance.jw_dom_node), c_void_p)
```

After defining a CFUNCTYPE for each of my callbacks I define my actual python functions that will be used in my callbacks.

```
def on_connected(self):
    print("on_connected callback has been called")

def on_disconnected(self):
    print("on_disconnected callback has been called")

def on_message_cb(self):
    print("on_message_cb has been called")
```

Now that I have created the actual functions to be called I create the actual instantiations of my CFUNCTYPE signatures.

```
self.callback__on_connected = self.pxgrid_connection_connect_cb(self.on_connected)
self.callback__connection_disconnect = self.pxgrid_connection_disconnect_cb(self.on_disconnected)
self.callback__message_cb = self.pxgrid_message_cb(self.on_message_cb)
```

Now in my core module I pass in the actual callback objects into the method calls that require them. (I will try to only include the relevant pieces of code that are needed for my current question.)

```
connection = POINTER(self.types.pxgrid_connection)()

self.lib.pxgrid_connection_set_connect_cb(ctypes.byref(connection), self.callbacks.callback__on_connected)
self.lib.pxgrid_connection_set_disconnect_cb(ctypes.byref(connection), self.callbacks.callback__connection_disconnect)

....Setting up addition properties for the connection

# call method to create actual connection
self.lib.pxgrid_connection_connect(connection)

# Call method to create a notification handler and pass in callback
self.handlers.create_session_notification(connection, self.callbacks.callback__message_cb)
```

I am able to successfully create my connection, connect to the server I am attempting to connect with and everything works great. However; none of my callbacks are ever hit. Is there something I am missing in the process of creating my CFUNCTYPE signatures and when creating the actual callbacks? Or am I just not creating my callback function signatures properly?

I know this was a bit long-winded but I wanted to provide enough information for what I am doing to hopefully assist with receiving some guidance from someone.

Thank you in advance, and If I am missing any information you need to answer this please let me know!

Thank you :)

Comment: I was actually able to solve this problem and it was due to a silly type on one of my callback functions names. So everything is working great now! I thought about deleting my question, but I will leave it in case anyone else is able to benefit from it :)

Comment: Hi, can you point me out how to wrap this c++ callback function to python code using ctype? `typedef BOOL (*PlayEndCallBack)(int UseListIndex,int UserMusicIndex,int DeviceCout,PUINT lpDeviceID,HWND hWnd,UINT TaskCode)`